# R Error - Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

Tags: r, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, monte-carlo, error

I have a dataset with salary information in various companies. I'm testing whether Job Title and Gender are dependent/independent of each other. However I'm running into an approximation error whenever I rune a Chi-squared test.

```
> gt
                              TopCompanyData.gender
TopCompanyData.title           Female Male
  Business Analyst                 45   86
  Data Scientist                  125  440
  Hardware Engineer                59  441
  Human Resources                  46   31
  Management Consultant            11   17
  Marketing                        84   89
  Mechanical Engineer              12   71
  Product Designer                192  268
  Product Manager                 361 1031
  Recruiter                        77   58
  Sales                            41   99
  Software Engineer              1334 9467
  Software Engineering Manager    100  844
  Solution Architect               29  325
  Technical Program Manager       163  383
> chisq = chisq.test(gt)
Warning message:
In chisq.test(gt) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> chisq 

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  gt
X-squared = 1027.7, df = 14, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I'm not sure if it is just the variables I'm using that is the issue or something else?

I also ran a Monte Carlo simulation

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  gt
X-squared = 1027.7, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

But I'll be honest, I'm not sure if it is right to apply this to my test. Can anyone explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I’m confused about how this relates to your salary data.

Answer (score 5):

There's a single expected value in the chi-squared that's below 5 (it's about 4.6). You can see it if you use `chisq.test(gt)$expected`.

R has implemented a common rule of thumb to check that the asymptotic chi-squared approximation will be reasonable -- one that is sometimes overly conservative (and, rather less frequently, not cautious enough). There are a number of other suggested rules than the one R uses -- and all the other ones I am familiar with would not complain about this case.

A further case in point is that the offending cell isn't among the major contributors to the chi-squared value - omitting or combining that row on the basis of the low expected count would still have left you with a chi-squared statistic well above 1000 on 12 d.f. (I am *not* suggesting you do this, only that you consider that it would not remotely change your conclusion if you had done so; *knowing* the value you'd get and deciding to do it on that basis would be a form of p-hacking. For all that it would be quite inconsequential here, it's not a habit to get into.)

That the p-value from the chi-squared approximation may not be as accurate as you might like (it probably isn't at all accurate so far out into the tail, offending cell or not) will be of no consequence, your p-value would be extremely small no matter how you decide to test it, with essentially any reasonable test -- you should reject at any typical significance level.

You could supplement your analysis -- for example by looking at the Pearson residuals for each cell, or by looking at the standardized residuals - to show that there are quite large effects throughout the table. (See the help to see how extract these tables in similar fashion to getting the expected values.)

You might have some substantive challenges to the validity of this analysis, but this particular issue really isn't among the challenges of any substance. In short, this specific issue should really be the least of your worries. (You may have to put some effort toward convincing others who are as easily spooked as you were by a warning triggered by an unproblematic violation of a very old, very rough rule of thumb.)

Note that with the simulated p-value your observed table was the most extreme value you got, so its value is really a very weak upper bound. If you want to do a simulated p-value based on resampling tables conditioning on the margins*, I'd suggest more simulations than that. For example 99,999 simulated values (`B=99999`) takes only a few seconds on my laptop, and I usually use a number like that since it's no trouble to get a more accurate value by waiting a few seconds. In this situation it will essentially always yield an estimated p-value of `1.e-5` (0.00001) because the observed table will still the most extreme one. I tried B=999999 (i.e. one short of a million) - which takes a few tens of seconds - and again no simulated table had a chi-squared statistic as large as the observed one. This would still almost certainly be the case if you did a billion simulations, if you had the enough hours to spare for it.

---

* conditioning on margins is not the same thing as assuming them to be fixed